# safe navigation (`&.`) をオペレータに対して実行したい

Tags: ruby

safe navigation を、例えば足し算オペレータや、 `[]` オペレータに対して実行したくなりました。これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか？

というのも、たとえば `+` であれば、

```
nillable_int + 3
```

`[]` であれば、

```
some_obj_not_responding_to_dig[:foo][:bar]
```

などを行うときなどに、 safe navigation が使えたらよいな、と思ったので質問しています。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` については大抵の場合 `at` を使うことが出来ます。
そちらを使うのがわかりやすい記述になり、良いかと思います。
`some_obj_not_responding_to_dig&.at(:foo)&.at(:bar)`

rubyの演算子は、実はただのメソッドです。
`def +()` などと定義し、演算子としてではなく、普通に呼び出しを行いたい場合
`lhs.+(rhs)` などの書き方が出来ます。
ここにsafe navigationを適用するなら、 `lhs&.+(rhs)` となります。

一応 `[]` も同様であるため
`some_obj_not_responding_to_dig&.[](:foo)&.[](:bar)`
という書き方も可能です。(`at`を薦めます)

Comment: 多階層の場合は #dig という選択もあります。Hash/Array/Struct/OpenStructに定義されています。

Comment: すみません not_responding_to_dig を見落としていました。